# Choosing the right list for unknown numbers

Tags: java

I need to program an application in Java language that has a pre-defined number of categories,
but the exact items in each category are unknown. Which one of the following data
structures I would use and why? Array, singly linked list, or doubly linked list

Comment: I'd pick the one that's fixed-length.

Comment: You’ll need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a map that contains a List, the implementation is irrelevant.

```
Map<Category, Collection<Item>> categoryMap
```

If the categories are ordered, use a TreeMap
If they're not ordered, use a Hashmap

If the items are known to be unique I'd have the Collection be a Hashset;
If the items are unique and ordered, I'd use a Treeset;
If they're non-unique, I'd use an ArrayList.

I see no reason to use a LinkedList of any variety if the number of entries are known. The reason to use LinkedLists is if there's to be many insertion/removal operations.

In almost all use cases an ArrayList is the superior implementation to use.  The only real downside to an ArrayList is if it's gets modified often, especially added to as it uses a "double up" method for resizing the internal array.  Basically, if it needs more room, it doubles the size of the existing array and then copy the items from the old array into the new array.  That can cause memory issue for large lists, but you'd need to be dealing with thousands of entries.